# How to write column as numbers when exporting to Excel in Pandas

Tags: pandas

I am exporting a table from HTML to Excel with Pandas. The command I am using for the export is:

```
print(all_tables.to_excel('master.xlsx', index=None, freeze_panes=(1,0))) # Print to excel
```

This works, but cells containing numbers are displayed as general text.

How can I make Pandas export these columns so that Excel can interpret them as number cells instead?

[image]

Comment: Maybe changing the decimal separator to `.` instead of `,` ?

Comment: I am using Excel in a nordic country so the decimal separator is `,`. Should probably have mentioned that. But even if I change it to `.` Excel understands the cell as general text.

Comment: Are you sure that your numeric columns have numerical dtypes in your dataframe?

Comment: You can use the to_excel() method with the float_format parameter.
 ```all_tables.to_excel('master.xlsx', index=False, float_format='%.2f')```

Comment: @PaulS I am not sure if the column have numerical dtypes. How can I check?

Comment: Run `all_tables.dtypes`, @Arete.

Comment: @PaulS The columns are just listed as Objects.

Comment: Then, you need to convert the numerical ones to `float`, @Arete.